# how to check which radio button is checked in android?

Tags: android, radio-button

Hi guys i have a 4 values i.e 4 radio buttons which i want to check if they are checked or not how will i do that ? i have tried this

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v){
    // Your code on click

    radioTypeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioType);
    radioTypeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int selectedId = radioTypeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_food);
            RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_fitness);
            RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_entertainment);
            RadioButton r4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_events);

            if (r1.isChecked()) {
                String food = "food";
                type = food;

            }
            if (r2.isChecked()) {
                String fitness = "fitness";
                type = fitness;


            }
```

But its not working  and i am assigning the type to another string  outside the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try implementing the following code

```
 RadioGroup  group= (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(i);
                int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is this doing exactly ?